# How can I make my Django code consume less memory?

Tags: django

I have an admin panel on my site.  I wish to do a one time initial data load and have created a button on my webpage which generates a http request which eventually makes its way to the following function:

```
def load_model(dbf_file, model, create_fn):
    db = dbf_reader.read_database(dbf_file)
    data = []
    for record in db:           
        data.append(create_fn(record))
        if len(data) == 300:
            model.objects.bulk_create(data)
            data = []
```

The function loads a .DBF file, and then reads the records one at a time.  It batches them into an array and then uses bulk_create to insert many records at once.  I have about 5mil records and Django consistently dies at 4mil.  It is a relatively small server with only 1gig of memory.  Is there something I can do to get Django to garbage collect or release resources?

Comment: Process smaller batches. That would do a lot for very little effort.

Comment: In `settings.py` is your `DEBUG` variable set to `FALSE`? I've had the same issue when inserting values in a db.